# Distinct rows by order

Tags: postgresql

I have the following SQL, generated from ActiveRecord in Rails 4 (partly with the Geocoder gem)

problem is, that even though `DISTINCT` is used, hopefully to get only unique items, the items returned duplicated. The reason for the duplication is that they can occur in several shops or brands (which is why I added the distinct, which doesn't quite help)

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.*,
                <calculate distance from shops coordinates> AS distance,
                <calculate bearing> AS bearing,
                items.*,
                shops.id AS closest_shop_id
FROM "items"
INNER JOIN "collection_items" ON "collection_items"."item_id" = "items"."id"
INNER JOIN "galleries" ON "galleries"."id" = "collection_items"."gallery_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN brands ON brands.id = galleries.galleriable_id
AND galleries.galleriable_type = 'Brand'
INNER JOIN shops ON shops.brand_id = brands.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN shops AS othershops ON galleries.galleriable_id = othershops.id
AND galleries.galleriable_type = 'Shops'
WHERE <shops coordinate are within some bounds>
ORDER BY updated_at DESC,
         distance ASC LIMIT 10
```

*things in `<` `>` are calculation simplification to make query less messy

How can I make this query return distinct items?

**Update:**

Checking with PGAdmin, I notice the results **are** distinct, but on everything, see data

[image]

So, to make these distincts, I need to decide which row to ignore.

**Is there a way to take only the first occurance (by the order specific) of the id column?**

such that it will take the first row of id 23171?

Comment: Any number of ways could be used to return distinct rows but we'd be guessing. What columns have data that is duplicated?  You'll have to break the query down and add each table individually and try to work past the duplicated data.

Comment: i updated the question with the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PostgreSQL you have to use the following if the rows are not identical considering all columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (column1, column2) * FROM ...
```

Comment: Is this answer still relevant to the question update I added?

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.id), items.* ... ORDER BY items.id, distance ;`

Comment: Is there a way to DISTINCT ON (items.id) without ordering by items.id? seems silly to sort by id...

Comment: If you need to `ORDER BY` on other field you need to wrap it in a subquery: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.id), items.* ... ORDER BY items.id, distance) AS subquery1 ORDER BY ...;` PostgreSQL is quite explicit on this: `ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`. You **can** leave the `ORDER BY ` out altogether.

Comment: hmm.. I guess life has its compromises..